# Deserealizar objeto en una clase, pero el objeto dentro del objeto lo guarda nulo

Tags: c#, json, .net

Deserealizo el json y lo guardo en la clase RootObject pero el objeto clspadres lo guarda vacio, ya hice el cambio que me comentaron, pero si coloco clspadres me tira error y no me carga los datos.

```
RootObject resultMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <RootObject>(resultJSON);

public class RootObject
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
    public string FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    public Lista<clspadres> Listapadres { get; set; }

}
public class clspadres 
{
    public string padre { get; set; }
    public string madre { get; set; }
}
```

Lo que me pasa es que Nombre, Apellido, Edad, FechaNacimiento si los llena pero clspadres los deja como nulos

Comment: Por el nombre quiero pensar que clspadres  deberia de ser una lista, y asi como lo estas poniendo no es lista como tal , tendrias que poner algo asi  public List<clspadres > Listapadres  { get; set; }

Comment: Ya lo genere como una lista pero igual me lo trae vacio, NULL y no se que mas hacer
La lista viene así
`"datos": {
        "Nombre ": "Moises",
        "Apellido ": "Masis",
        "Edad ": "24",
        "FechaNacimiento ": "09/09/1996",
        "clspadres ": {
            "padre": "Juan",
            "madre ": "Maria"
        }
    }`

Comment: El detalle esta en el nombre que le pones intenta con esto asi mira public List<clspadres > clspadres { get; set; }

Comment: Como seria eso ???

Comment: prueba como te puse

Comment: Listo ya lo hice y si lo coloco como lista me cae a mi catch como error

Comment: pon tu codigo modificado, edita la pregunta, lo que cometa @EdgarVazquez te deberia de funcionar.

Comment: Si ya hice el cambion, pero lo hice como me dijiste y me tira al catch como error de json y al deserealizar ahi no almacena los datos en la clase

Comment: @MoiMasis prueba de este modo public clspadres clspadres { get; set; }, veo que no es una lista si no un objeto entonces como lista no te funcionaria el error estaba en que no tenia el nombre correcto, checa como te digo y dime si te funciono

Answer (score 0):

esto te deveria de funcionar:

```html
RootObject resultMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <RootObject>(resultJSON);

public class RootObject
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
    public string FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    public List<clspadres>  clspadres { get; set; }

}
public class clspadres 
{
    public string padre { get; set; }
    public string madre { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo hice así y no me compila me da error de json al deserializar

Comment: cual es el error?, en que linea?,pegalo aca

Comment: El no me genera ningún error corre normal, solo que no me guarda esos datos en la clase

Comment: agrega un punto de interrupcion en la linea donde estas deserializando el json y corre paso a paso para ver porque no carga la clase con datos.

Comment: Ya lo puse ahí pero no me tira ningun error

Comment: entonces revisa que tu json tenga datos.

Comment: En efecto tiene datos los campos papa y mama los tiene y son string

Comment: como estas recorriendo la clase para ver que no te este guardando datos?

Comment: lo único que hago es deserealizar el json en la clase y listo. Me trae todos los datos excepto los de padre y madre